# C: GCC Compilation "Cannot find -lglfw3"

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, glfw

I am starting a game project and decided to install GLFW for my windowing. When I did this, I had to google how to set it up as I'm new to GCC and the C language. I keep on getting this error and I can't figure out what is wrong with the way it is being compiled. Here is the rough hierarchy of my project:

```
Project Dir
   -src
      -main.c
   -scripts
      -run.bat
   -thirdparty
      -GLFW
        -lib
        -include
```

The GCC command I am trying to run is below:

```
gcc src/main.c -o Game-Name -I/thirdparty/GLFW/include -L/thirdparty/GLFW/lib -lglfw3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any further questions or wanna see any source code let me know and I'll respond with it

Comment: `-I/thirdparty/GLFW/include` -> `-I thirdparty/GLFW/include` because `/` at the start is an absolute path which is not what you need. Same for `-L`.

Comment: same with `-L/thirdparty`